# Why "yourself" instead of "you"?

Tags: word-choice, personal-pronouns

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (2004)* movie, Tom says to Harry Potter about Hedwig, an owl:

> Tom: Right smart bird you got there, Mr. Potter. He arrived here just
> five minutes before **yourself**.

Why "yourself" instead of "you"?

Source: Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (2004)

Comment: It could be replaced with "you", but would possibly be better (thought of as being) replaced with "your good self" as this would more easily lead the reader to see it as intentionally respectful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is rather subtle, but using "yourself" like this is a marker of social status.  The word "yourself" can be used to mean "you" in a in an honorific way.  So it marks Tom as being low status compared to Harry.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-reflexive-myself-themselves-etc) gives an example

> The National Trust is a charity depending on the support of people like yourself. (or … people like you.)

Note also Tom's dialect use of "right" in this sentence, and his addressing of a boy as "Mr Potter". The author is using these clues to let us judge the type of person that Tom is.

Comment: Many people find a related usage ('myself' instead of 'me') to be deeply annoying.

Comment: Absolutely. I bet that on average, the construction *people **like yourself** are [adjectival description]* is far more likely to feature a ***favourable*** description than *people **like you** are...* Where I'd also expect "favourable" assessments to use ***such as*** more often than ***like***, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: I took it as dialect. In RP it would sound odd and not a polite form. The National Trust example is different.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: It's not *formal* language / usage if that's what you mean, but it is how that character speaks when choosing to be *polite* / respectful.  ([Tom](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Tom), landlord of the Leaky Cauldron, according to some quick googling.).

Comment: I had quick check of the video of the scene in question and Tom is speaking in a dialect in which "yourself" would be used that way more than in standard British English. I'm just flagging that up because a learner might not realise that what they are reading is meant to sound that way.